# Is it possible to make something equivalent to active binding to the empty string?

Tags: r, read-eval-print-loop

#### Inspiration

I use that hack to quickly show the content of the working directory:

```
makeActiveBinding(".", function() { dir() }, .GlobalEnv)
```

Now you can just eval the `.`:

```
.
#> [1] "test.Rproj" "DESCRIPTION"    "LICENSE"        "man"            "NAMESPACE"      "R"              "tests"
```

---

#### Question

Is there a way to add this kind of behavior to the REPL when you eval nothing, I mean when you just hit `ENTER` at the empty prompt?

---

#### Effort

```
makeActiveBinding("", function() { dir() }, .GlobalEnv)
```

but it raises this error:

```
Error in as.name(sym) : attempt to use zero-length variable name
```

You HAVE TO bind to a symbol and `""` is not a valid one...

Comment: What's the advantage of this over `.  <- dir()`? Also what is your overall goal? If you're trying to run something every time a command is executed, you might want to look at [`addTaskCallback()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/taskCallback.html)

Comment: @SamR (1) If you do `. <- dir()`, the `.` variable created will not update when you change the working directory... (2) Not every time but **only when nothing is typed on the prompt** <=> just hitting `ENTER`

Comment: That would have to be done by the front end, it won't be done by R.  I don't know if RStudio has any support for it, but the standard R front end doesn't.

Comment: No offense, I am just really curious. Why would we need this instead of just calling "dir()"? Is it important to create a binding instead of calling a function? "dir()" or "dir(getwd())" or "list.files()" do update programatically

Comment: @GuedesBF As said in the Inspiration part: "to quickly show the content of the wd" and obviously typing a dot is not quick enough for the OP...

Comment: @user2554330 good thought - sounds like the purpose is for interactive use and this would be straightforward to add as a keybinding in vscode. . Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Another possibility would be to hook into the completion mechanism.  Then a TAB on a blank line could print the info you want.  I don't know how to do that though.

Comment: Ok got it, I just think this is too much hassle for little benefit, an IDE snippet/shortcut/binding is likely the way to go.

Comment: @SamR RStudio is the IDE, I could make an Addin...

Comment: Would adding `snippet .
 dir()` to the snippets tab in Rstudio do the trick? It is just one extra keystroke (TAB) away and clearly obviates the need for "working directory adjustments"

Comment: @GuedesBF why not. Thanks for the ideas here! I will use Addin bound to ALT+ENTER to list files and a `snippet cd` to change dir easily...

Comment: while at that, {bindr} might come in handy, too: https://krlmlr.github.io/bindr/